# elasticsearch in docker cluster name is same but not clustering

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, cluster-computing

$ curl localhost:9200/_cat/health?v

epoch      timestamp cluster    status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1469016273 12:04:33  jh-cluster green           1         1      0   0    0    0        0             0                  -                100.0%

$ curl localhost:9201/_cat/health?v

epoch      timestamp cluster    status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1469016277 12:04:37  jh-cluster green           1         1      0   0    0    0        0             0                  -                100.0%

I don't know why this situation. Nodes's config file is same,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste your elastic configuration, btw this is my configuration for cluster in local (1 master-for-write 1 slave-for-read):

master node:

```
cluster.name: musement
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9301
http.port: 9201

node.master: true
node.data: false
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["pippo.int:9300"]
```

slave node:

```
cluster.name: musement
network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 3s
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["pippo.int:9301"]
```

where pippo.int it's the eth0 of my pc